# How to make startx open new X Session in tty7?

Tags: display, xorg, startx

Before, when I launched x from the tty1 console, it would start the x session in tty7, allowing me to terminate it easily from tty1. Now (I do not know what changed it), `startx` from tty1 will open X in tty1. How can I change it so it will open in tty7?

Answer (score 1):

The vt used can be specified as an argument/option when starting the Xserver - it is **`vt#`** where `#` is a number greater than zero and will (must?) be after the display(.screen) number, typically `:0` - note that a leading `-` is NOT used for this option.  Depending on the display manager this may be influenced by settings in the configuration for that.  For example, the `lightdm` display manager has a setting in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file, in the `[LightDM]` section for `minimum-vt` which in my case has the default value of `7`.

Comment: My lightdm conf file has `7` for `minimum-vt` as well. Why isn't X starting in tty7 then?

Comment: Not sure, if you do a `ps aux | grep vt` do you get a line for the X server - it will be something like `... /usr/bin/X -config .... :0 vt# ...` - what is the `#`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to type `sudo apt-get purge startx` then you need to install it again so you can type `sudo apt-get install startx`. After you did that you will need to edit the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and set `minimum-vt` to `7`.